# Show that $H *_{G} (G/N) \cong H/N'$ where $f(N)=N' \subset H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-property

I was doing some group theory and this exercise came up.

Let $f: G \to H$ be a group morphism and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Denote $\pi: G \to G/N$  and let $N'$ be the normal closure of $f(N)$. Show that the amalgamated product $H*_G(G/N) \cong H/N'$.

I want to use the universal property for the amalgamated product. Since we can make a homomorphism $\varphi: H \to H/N'$ and a homomorphism $\psi : G/N \to H/N'$ we know there must be a unique homomorphism from $\alpha: H *_G (G/N) \to H/N'$. 
Now since it holds for $q_H : H \to H *_G (G/N) $ that $\alpha \circ q_H = \varphi$, we obtain that $\alpha$ must also be surjective. I can't seem to figure out however how I should prove that $\alpha$ is injective.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do the expressions $H/N$ and $G/N'$ make sense if $N\unlhd G$ and $N'\unlhd H$?

Comment: I think there is a typo, it should be $H*_G(G/N) \cong H/N'$. And $G/N'$ does not make sense.

Comment: I think that the best approach to this is to prove that $H/N'$ has the required universal property of the amalgamated free product. Then you can just use the uniqueness property of the amalgamated product.

Comment: @DerekHolt sorry for the typo's

Comment: What do you mean with the uniqueness property?

Comment: It is a feature of universal properties that they define objects up to isomorphism.

Comment: So if we work with the above definitions, there exist $q_H: H \to H *_G (G/N)$ and $q_{G/N}: G/N \to H *_G (G/N)$. Are you saying that I should also be making $q'_H : H \to H/N'$ and $q'_{G/N}: G/N \to H/N'$. And then say we can make morphisms from $H/N'$ and $H *_G (G/N)$ to another group and therefore they are the same?

Comment: Using one well-known, widespread used notation for *another* thing is, imo, a very bad idea: I can't stop thinking of $\;N'\;$ as the derived (even the name!) or commutator group of $\;N\;$, whereas here it is the normal closure ...of $\;f(N)\;$ ! Not even within the same group . One usual (the most, imo) notation for normal clusre is $\;f(N)^G\;$ ...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the next time. Thanks!

Comment: @DonAntonio: I hope we can agree to differ about that! I find that naming related groups $G$ and $G'$ is often very convenient, and it is irritating that this usage should be banned because some people would like to reserve it for the commutator subgroup, which you can always denote by $[G,G]$. But I agree in this case that it might have been clearer to write $f(N)^G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt could you give me some follow-up on my comment, please? :)

Comment: You referred to the universal property of amalgamated products yourself, in your question, so you must know what it means.

Comment: When beginning and if there's nothing else I can agree with you @DerekHolt. Not in this case at all, though: once the derived subgroup kicks in, I think there're lots of symbols out there to use and not precisely that one.